# Django-CMS gives 'cms_toolbar_login_error' when DEBUG is False

Tags: python, django, django-cms

this has been troubling me for a while and I cannot find anyone else suffering from the same problem as I am,

I've installed DjangoCMS 3.0.2 and on it, I'm trying to use `cmsplugin_contact` (I've done the integration and the pages load fine). It seems to work fine in debug mode, where a thank you message is shown on submission. Things go awry the moment I flip the `DEBUG` flag to `False`.

The Apache Server gives a '200 Error', which means that the request succeeded, but then something snapped. Examining the traceback in error logs, the CMS tags seem to be the culprit. Apparently, the `request` object is not being passed and I don't understand why.

Here's the traceback:

```
File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 224, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return callback(request, **param_dict)
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/django/utils/functional.py", line 15, in _curried
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return _curried_func(*(args+moreargs), **dict(kwargs, **morekwargs))
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/django/views/defaults.py", line 41, in server_error
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return http.HttpResponseServerError(template.render(Context({})))
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self._render(context)
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self.nodelist.render(context)
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render_node
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return node.render(context)
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/classytags/core.py", line 106, in render
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/sekizai/templatetags/sekizai_tags.py", line 75, in render_tag
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return nodelist.render(context)
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render_node
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return node.render(context)
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/classytags/core.py", line 106, in render
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/craft/env/lib/python2.7/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py", line 607, in render_tag
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     context['cms_toolbar_login_error'] = request.GET.get('cms-toolbar-login-error', False) == '1'
[Wed May 28 23:12:17 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GET'
```

This problem had also arisen before, when I was not using the `cmsplugin_contact` module, but was resolved by setting the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` value and commenting out the `TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG` flags. Now, it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?